# How to get my calculator program to accept 0

Tags: ruby

I would like to get my program to accept `0` as a number. After some searching, I found a formula that might work but how do I implement it to my 
program? The code is:

```
def integer?(input)
  input.to_i.to_s == input
end
```

I want to add it to this block of code. Keep in mind that `valid_number?` is a method I created. Do I write another `if` statement?

```
loop do
  prompt("Whats the first number")
  number1 = Kernel.gets().chomp().to_i

  if valid_number?(number1)
    break
  else
    prompt("Not a number")
  end
end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about code we need a minimal example of your code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As a note, when working with Ruby, empty argument lists are usually omitted and specifying `Kernel` for kernel methods is only necessary if you have another method with the same name in your current scope. That is, say `gets.chomp.to_i` instead.

Comment: @Tadman also no need for `chomp`.

Answer (score 2):

```
loop do
  puts "Whats the first number"
  number1 = gets.chomp

  if number1.to_i.to_s == number1
    break
  else
    puts "Not a number"
  end
end
```

The problem with your code (assuming `integer?` and `valid_number?` are the same method) is that you convert `number1` to integer before passing it to the checker. The checker as you have it posted expects a string as an input.